# Implementing Popups using ConstraintLayout in Android Studio (java)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, popupwindow

I am trying to design a popup UI to expand an already displayed image on my activity_main using android studios new ConstraintLayout UI design technology. The sources I've seen only show examples for LinearLayout or RelativeLayout. Is there an alternative way to do this using ConstraintLayout instead?

Comment: From your question I'm not sure what the problem is. A popup/dialog's layout is a layout just like any other.

Comment: How would it be implemented from the java code?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs

Comment: That's the issue, I'm not looking to use LinearLayout

Comment: You just replace the linear layout with the coordinator layout.

Comment: Can you post some code or a picture so as to what you are hinting at.